# How to use ng-animate to set a JS animation for ng-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, gsap

Can do something like:

```
<section ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'showExpand', leave: 'showExpand'}" id="mainContent">
</section>
```

while showExpand is animation in JS:

```
angular.animation(".showExpand", function () {
        return {
            enter: function(element, done){
                TweenMax.to(element, .8, {opacity: 1, top: '35pt'});
                done();
            },
            leave: function(element, done){
                TweenMax.to(element, .8, {opacity: 0, top: '-45pt'});
                done();
            },
            addClass: function (element, className) {
                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {opacity: 1, top: '35pt'});
            },
            removeClass: function (element, className) {
                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {opacity: 0, top: '-45pt'});
            }
        }
    };
);
```

I have tried:

```
 ng-animate="{enter: 'showExpand', leave: 'showExpand'}"
    ng-animate="{enter: 'show-expand', leave: 'show-expand'}"
    ng-animate="{enter: '.showExpand', leave: '.showExpand'}"
    ng-animate="{enter: '.show-expand', leave: '.show-expand'}"
```

And I cannot find anything for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the new [docs for ngAnimate from Angular 1.2 onwards](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs) you no longer use the ng-animate tag.

And you need to add the class you defined. So it should be:

`<section ng-view class="showExpand" id="mainContent"></section>`

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it without using class? What if I want to specify too different animations for enter and leave? Specifying both in class attribute?

Comment: No ngAnimate is linked to the classes. You can add another class to it and make another animation linked to that class. Or you can specify two different animations in the enter and leave functions based on some condition.

Comment: There's no other way to go about it, other than to revert the ngAnimate to an earlier version and that might cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may a angular version problem

Please see this sample :

http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: That site is outdated. The docs I mentioned in my answer are up by the developers themselves.